# Use CloudFlare so I can access website hosted in Azure via IP Address

Tags: azure-web-app-service, cloudflare

I am very new to Cloudflare. So please bear with me. I need to access my website (hosted in Microsoft Azure - App Services) via IP address instead of the domain name.

To do this, I need to add `HOST=www.mydomain.com` into the HTTP header when requesting the website via IP address.

I heard it can be solved via Cloudflare, but the person I asked will not elaborate further. Is it possible? If yes, what service should I purchase? Any manual or instruction will be appreciated.

If Cloudflare isn't possible, do you have any service recommendations?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the host header is needed is because Azure App Services are multi-tenant (multiple apps on a single IP) by default. So, the server needs some way to know where to route your request to (the host name). In addition, IPs are not guaranteed to be static (they can change as you scale for instance).

It should be possible to secure a single static IP address using the following method -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-a-static-inbound-ip

What is unclear is whether or not this IP would also be *dedicated* (meaning only your domain would use it). This is what would be required in order to allow you to access the app service without a hostname specified.

Cloudflare will not solve this issue, as it sits at the DNS layer (domain name access). Accessing a server via IP would bypass Cloudflare entirely.

Comment: To add to this, it sounds like only App Services in the `Isolated tier` of pricing would have a dedicated IP address - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#how-ip-addresses-work-in-app-service

The other option would be to move your web application to an Azure VM (or other host) that does not share IPs.

May be worth revisiting or explaining the requirement of *why* you need access via IP, as this is pretty uncommon.

Comment: I have this single static IP. But like you said, it is multitenant, I need a way in Cloudflare (or any 3rd party) to allow me to inject the host to the HTTP request header.

Comment: Almost any software that makes HTTP requests will allow you to add any headers you'd like (including the HOST header). What they can't do is negate the need of Azure to have that value. What language / library are you using to make the HTTP request?

Comment: It is just a standard browser (ie. Chrome/FireFox/Edge/etc...). I just need to be able to access the website via IP Address.

Comment: Using only a web browser, there's not really a great solution for silently adding custom HTTP headers to a given request. If you want to go into the *why* you need to access by IP specifically (and not a domain name), it may help with alternative solutions?

Comment: That is right, but the person I asked was able to use IP access, just does not elaborate further on how to do it. I am hoping someone is able to help me :)